# Tiles not shown on cesium

Tags: akka, tile, cesiumjs

I created a viewer and added a customized layer (which is provided by myself). I am using the `akka` map server. My problem is that my map tiles are not displayed, although I can see from the console that cesium has loaded the tiles.

The code looks like this:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;
var through = layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
    url : 'http://my_ip:8777/modis/ndvi/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    format: "image/png"
}));
through.alpha = 0.5;
```

If I change the `url` to another map such as `blackmarble`, it loads correctly
(i.e. the tiles are displayed, but the position y must be changed to reverseY). Does any body know why my map can't be loaded on the `cesium`?

Comment: I corrected some of the grammar in the question, and removed unnecessary works (eg Thanks). I added the akka tag

Comment: @CocoNess Thanks! Forgive my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

I had found the key point.
Cesium must add CORS add the TMS which you want add it to your layers.
So just add the akka CORS suport,then everything will ok!